# How do you use MATCH in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an error in the below code and its likely incorrect syntax.

I have tried replacing this line

```
IsInArray(pdfname, arNames(i)) = True
```

with this

```
Application.worksheetfunction.match(pdfname, arNames(i)) = True
```

but its not working.

```
 Sub OpenPdf()

    On Error GoTo OpenPdf_Error

    Dim pdfname As String
    Dim pdf
    Const sPath = "S:\RA QUOTES 2019"
    Dim FName As String
    Dim arNames() As String
    Dim myCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    FName = Dir("S:\RA QUOTES 2019\*.pdf*")
    Do Until FName = ""
        myCount = myCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve arNames(1 To myCount)
        arNames(myCount) = FName
        FName = Dir
        Loop


    pdfname = Application.InputBox("Enter the pdf you are looking for")
    pdfname = "PLQ" & pdfname




For i = 1 To UBound(arNames)

If IsInArray(pdfname, arNames(i)) = True Then

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sPath & arNames(i)

     End If

    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

OpenPdf_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure OpenPdf"

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and does it occur on the line that you've quoted? Looks to me like the second argument of `Match()` should be `arNames` instead of `arNames(i)`.

Comment: `IsInArray()` is a custom function, do you have it?

Comment: Damian 

   Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
   End Function

Comment: Its saying type mismatch for the custom function

Comment: Do yo uneed an aproximate match, or full match @TechTutors?

Comment: @Damian I need an approximate. 

The user needs to find PLQ1000 for example, but the actual file will always contain a name with it, say PLQ1000-John.pdf
They generally just search for the PLQ number, which is 1000 in this case, and it should open PLQ1000-John.pdf

Comment: @TechTutors last question... is there a pattern on the PDF, are all PQLXXXX just 4 numbers and then "-" and a name? Or all the PDF have a "-" to separate the PQL and number from the name?

Comment: @Damian all are PLQxxxx. After PLQxxxx the characters can vary.

 So it could be PLQ1052 John.pdf and PLQ1025_Client.pdf. Those PLQxxxx will always be there. But theres not much I can do for the characters afterwards

Comment: @TechTutors check my edit, try it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for an **exact match** using a dictionary (a collection data type which has the `.Exists` property which allows you to check if a key within the dictionary exists without looping through everytime).

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenPdf()

    Dim pdfname As String
    Dim DictPDF As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Needs Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Const sPath = "S:\RA QUOTES 2019\"

    Dim FName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    FName = Dir(sPath & "*.pdf*")
    Do While FName <> vbNullString
        'add the name into the dictionary
        DictPDF.Add Left(LCase(pdfname), 7), 1 'Left will get the first 7 characters from the left to the name
        FName = Dir
    Loop

    pdfname = Application.InputBox("Enter the pdf you are looking for")
    pdfname = LCase("PLQ" & pdfname)

    'Check if the name is in the dictionary I used LCase because dictionaries are case sensitive,
    'so everything in low case to avoid problems.
    If DictPDF.Exists(pdfname) Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sPath & DictPDF(pdfname)
    Else
        MsgBox pdfname & " was not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It should work, but i dont know what this line is for
Dim DictPDF As New Scripting.Dictionary

Comment: You need to go to tools-->reference and look for `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` then check it.

Comment: Alright, but now its giving a runtime error with this line

DictPDF.Add Left(LCase(pdfname), 7), 1

Comment: @TechTutors that means that you have duplicated PLQXXXX is that possible?

Comment: It can be named PLQxxxx and PLQxxxxA. So it may be picking up more than one PLQxxxx, but that is what is needed. . It must open all the pdfs containing PLQxxxx.

Comment: @Damain thanks for the help. I finally figured it out. the below was the problem

    If InStr(1, arNames(i), pdfname, vbTextCompare)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub OpenPdf()

On Error GoTo OpenPdf_Error

Dim pdfname As String
Dim pdf
Const sPath = "S:\RA QUOTES 2019\"
Dim FName As String
Dim arNames() As String
Dim myCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

FName = Dir("S:\RA QUOTES 2019\*.pdf*")
Do Until FName = ""
    myCount = myCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve arNames(1 To myCount)
    arNames(myCount) = FName
    FName = Dir
    Loop


pdfname = Application.InputBox("Enter the pdf you are looking for")
pdfname = "PLQ" & pdfname





For i = 1 To UBound(arNames)

If InStr(1, arNames(i), pdfname, vbTextCompare) Then

MsgBox (arNames(i))

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sPath & arNames(i)

 End If

Next i

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

OpenPdf_Error:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure 
OpenPdf"

End Sub
```